# Why is my Android Studio project not getting the Pebble sdk through the build.gradle?

Tags: android, pebble-watch

I have looked for a few hours and not found a solution that works.

So the instructions say:

Add PebbleKit Android to an Android Studio project in the app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.getpebble:pebblekit:3.0.0'
}
```

my build.gradle (module app) has this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0')
    compile compile 'com.getpebble:pebblekit:3.0.0@aar'
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: compile is written for two times.

Comment: yeah, that was a typo here. removed it and still nothing